# ZipFile inside a ZipFile (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

**BACKGROUND**

I have some directory in my home directory called `delivery_content`. Inside that directory there are two folders `content_123` and `content_456`. Each directory contains a text file. So the over all structure looks like the following.

```
-delivery_content
 -content_123/
   -content_123.txt
 -content_456/
   -content_456.txt
```

I am writing code that when given a directory it will zip all of it's contents.

**CODE**

```
import os
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime


DOWNLOAD_DIR = Path(os.getenv("HOME")) / "delivery_content"

date = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
delivery_name = f"foo_{date}"
shutil.make_archive(str(DOWNLOAD_DIR / delivery_name), "zip", str(DOWNLOAD_DIR))
print("Zipping Has Complete")
```

So for the given code above i expect to see a foo_todays_date.zip in the `DOWNLOAD_DIR` and when i unzip it i expect to see the following

```
 -content_123/
   -content_123.txt
 -content_456/
   -content_456.txt
```

However I see the following[image]

Is there a way i can avoid having a .zip inside my zipfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are putting the zip file inside the directory that you are archiving. `make_archive` is probably creating an empty file to verify it can write to the destination before it starts archiving. So it then sees the empty zip file as a file to archive. The only way I see around this using the `make_archive` function is to put the archive file outside of the directory to archive like below:

```
shutil.make_archive(str(DOWNLOAD_DIR / ".."/ delivery_name), "zip", str(DOWNLOAD_DIR))
```

You can always move the zip file into the DOWNLOAD_DIR afterward.

Comment: The confusing part for me is which argument specifies where the zipped file will be outputted? Why do you use ".." ? What does that indicate?

Comment: The first argument specifies where to put the zip file. The ".." says to put in the directory above DOWNLOAD_DIR. I just picked that location arbitrarily. There might be a better place in your circumstance, but only you would know that.